# React Router Configure Custom Root

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Typically all react router examples that I have seen are with root path starts with "/". Because our server is configured "/" root for a different application, we needed to configure "/ReactApp". With this configuration, I am not able to run nested routes like /ReactApp/Details. Below is my route configuration

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/ReactApp" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="detail" component={Detail} />
    </Route>
    </Router>
</Provider>,
```

Trying to achieve below component execution. First route works but not able to run second router

**Route**       ----         **Component**

/ReactApp       ----        App -> Dashboard

/ReactApp/detail ----       App -> Detail

Any pointers?

Thank You

Comment: Which version of react-router do you use

Comment: react-router 3.0.2